# I need help creating a graph in python with matplotlib. Data must be read from JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"rpm": [
{"Clock": "09:55:44", "Value": 767.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:45", "Value": 759.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:47", "Value": 2302.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:48", "Value": 1973.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:49", "Value": 2199.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:51", "Value": 1040.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:52", "Value": 757.0}, 
{"Clock": "09:55:53", "Value": 737.0},
......
]}
```

I have to display on a tkinter page, a graph with this data.
Axis x is for "Clock".
Axis y is for "Value".

I have tried with:

```
with open('rpm.json') as ff:
    data = json.load(ff)

dates = [i['Clock'] for i in data['rpm']]
values = [i['Value'] for i in data['rpm']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'values': values})
df['dates'] = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]

print(df.sort_values(by='dates'))

figura1=plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5),dpi=100)
ax1=figura1.add_subplot(111)
bar1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(figura1,self)
bar1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH)
df.plot(kind='bar',legend=True,ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('TITLE')
```

But it gives me errors.

Can you help me?

Comment: What errors? What have you tried to fix them?

Comment: ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units .... I do not understand where. Is the code written by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace part of you code beginning from figura1 with this;

```
root = tk.Tk()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bar=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
bar.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH)
df.plot(kind='bar', x='dates', y='values', ax=ax, legend=True)
ax.set_title('TITLE')
tk.mainloop()
```